# Does the Python if statement implicitly apply bool to objects found in the conditional?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have a working selenium program that contains this code:

```
nxt_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn--alt')
print(type(nxt_page))
if nxt_page:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', nxt_page)
    print(type(nxt_page))
    nxt_page.click()
```

(see [Scraping Duckduckgo with Python 3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772329/8929814)

When the program runs, the two print statement show

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
```

Question: If you use an object for the [if conditional], like

```
if OBJECT:
    print('found')
```

is python simply substituting `bool(OBJECT)` for the conditional?

Is it always the case that `bool(OBJECT)` is False if `OBJECT == None`? I wouldn't think that a programmer could tamper with that. You could then equivalently write

```
if nxt_page is not None:
    ect.
```

Before posting this I just found [Boolean value of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python)
, and that is certainly helpful.

Comment: take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__

Comment: Yes. 11 more characters to go...

Comment: In that link you provided, had a link to the Python docs to [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) which says that internally `bool()` checks `__nonzero__` first, then `__len__` functions.

Comment: The linked question seems to answer your question, so I'm not really sure what you're asking. It isn't always the case that `bool(OBJECT)` is False if `OBJECT == None` because one can be customized with `__bool__` and the other with `__eq__`

Comment: `__nonzero__` predates `bool` and is not used in 3.x.  Tests for `None` should use `is` or `is not`.

Comment: @miradulo The comments and answers here are all helpful. Years ago I programmed in Cobol. I find python to be amazingly expressive!

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Now using `if nxt_page is not None:`. Remember reading about this syntax before, and I am getting more comfortable with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans) is very clear on how values are evaluated in a boolean context:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.